# ISO 27001 - Companies processing each other's data

Tags: iso27001

If there are two companies, each holding a valid ISO 27001 certification, what type of formal relationship can be established in policy to allow each other to access, process and store each other's information assets?

Lets for example say:

- Company "ACME" acquired Company "XX".
- Both are ISO 27001 certified.
- they need to disclose some information assets to each other. (Like ACME needs to review the financials for company XX including things like employee records, salaries, etc.)

Without re-writing the scopes of both or merging the two ISMS's - how does one establish a framework that allows "general" access?

Options I'm considering:

- Write an agreement and treat each other as a supplier.
- Map information classifications between both. Then include a policy in each ISMS detailing this mapping. (Then information from XX automatically gets mapped in ACME with known storage, handling and disclosure requirements meeting the control objectives already used by XX).
- or create a classification label in each company for the other company's information - this likely means the information would be at the most secure level on the recipient side - and doesn't allow for much granularity around disclosure.

Hope this makes sense - happy to add more detail if anyone needs.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are seeing in this situation. Why would scopes need to be changed to process *data*? You simply write a data sharing agreement. Look to GDPR for models to borrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to address as much as I can since there is a lot here.

> If there are two companies, each holding a valid ISO 27001 certification, what type of formal relationship can be established in policy to allow each other to access, process and store each other's information assets?

ISO doesn't have anything to do with it. Yes, I prefer my data processor to have a good SOC 2 and ISO 27001. That's just part of the vendor management policy and risk assessment. However, the relationship is contractual. Company A may have Company B as a data processor. The actual agreement would be arranged with the Data Processing Agreement (DPA). The DPA may be what you're looking for in this scenario.

> Lets for example say:
> Company "ACME" acquired Company "XX".
> Both are ISO 27001 certified.
> they need to disclose some information assets to each other. (Like ACME needs to review the financials for company XX including things like employee records, salaries, etc.)

They would have disclosed the business operational information already at this point. It would have been handled by a broker with company information in escrow so there is confidentiality should the deal fall though. But to indulge the acquisition happened...

First, I want to be clear this is a completely different scenario than the above where it was a mutual agreement without acquisition. It also carries with it a myriad of possibilities depending on the nature of the acquisition. Was it a merger? Strictly asset acquisition? Is the other company considered a subsidiary? Each will have different actions. However, I will provide context with what I know and have experienced for better accuracy.

Let's assume the one company completely acquired the other. First, for company data, a DPA is not needed. Everyone gets their paycheck from the same employer.The same company owns all the assets, customer accounts, branding and everything else under the former's banner.

Now let's say each offer a product, which processes their reflective customers' data. Things get weird here. Assuming the contacts from each company are still honored, then a DPA would be needed should customer data be processed on one platform and then another as well. Let me know if this doesn't make sense to you.

Essentially, let's say I bought licenses to use software Foo. They have competitor Bar which offers similar services as well. Foo acquires Bar. Now Foo owns the accounts, software, products, et al. Foo, in an effort to merge products or move customers to their own, approach customers saying, "We would like to offer access to Foobar2.0 for free." In this case, even though they are the same company (Foo + Bar), they would need to either create a supplement to their DPA, create a new one, or renegotiate the contract all together. Since the scope has changed between each product. Here's the fun part though... (and this is what I went through when my employer acquired their competitor) you could hypothetically not need to re-invent the wheel as all of the acquired company is subject to their new owner's policies. So however data was classed or managed would be in the same methodology. Company Bar does not have employees. They all answer to Foo and will abide by those policies.

> Options I'm considering:
> Write an agreement and treat each other as a supplier.

A supplier to each other? It sounds like there is a lot left to be said about the acquisition of the lawyers haven't figured out transfer of ownership yet. I would leave this to the lawyers to figure out. Having each company beholden to the other is circular and doesn't leave much to be said about duty of care.

> Map information classifications between both. Then include a policy in each ISMS detailing this mapping.

1. Yes map data classes so they are consistent
2. Absolutely do not create a duplicate policy. Each should work from the same data classification policy. How it may be implemented in two environments may vary but they should both fulfill the policy requirements.

> (Then information from XX automatically gets mapped in ACME with known storage, handling and disclosure requirements meeting the control objectives already used by XX).
> or create a classification label in each company for the other company's information - this likely means the information would be at the most secure level on the recipient side - and doesn't allow for much granularity around disclosure.

I'd think the data policy and class would dictate handling. By all means, there should be parity.

> Hope this makes sense - happy to add more detail if anyone needs.

Oh absolutely no sense to me at all but I did my best. The TL;DR is:

1. Thinking about a merger/acquisition? The lawyers hash this out and use a broker which holds information in escrow.
2. Actually merged/acquired? One policy to rule them all. Procedures are subject to vary as stakeholders work out the details of complying.